# The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join, linq-to-entities

While trying to execute this query:

```
var query = from dpr in ctx.DPR_MM
            join q in ctx.QOT on dpr.DPR_QOT_ID equals qot_id
            join p in ctx.PAY_MM on new { q.QOT_SEC_ID, dpr.DPR_TS } equals new { p.PAY_SEC_ID, p.PAY_DATE }
            where q.QOT_ID = qot_id
            select new
            {
                dpr.dpr_ts,
                dpr.dpr_close,
                pay.First().pay_dividend
            };
```

I'm getting this error:

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.
>   Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

`QOT_SEC_ID` is of type `decimal` and  `PAY_SEC_ID` is of type `int32`.
I'm not allowed to change it in the table.

No matter what I do, I'm not able to change it in model's properties.
I have tried to convert the types like this:

```
join p in ctx.PAY on new { sec_id = (Int32)(q.QOT_SEC_ID), dpr.DPR_TS } equals new { sec_id = (Int32)p.PAY_SEC_ID, p.PAY_DATE }
```

but getting the error above.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

The types *and* the names of the properties in the anonymous types must match:

```
new { p1 = q.QOT_SEC_ID, p2 = dpr.DPR_TS } 
    equals 
new { p1 = (decimal)p.PAY_SEC_ID, p2 = p.PAY_DATE }
```

or if `p.PAY_SEC_ID` were an `int?`:

```
new { p1 = (int?)q.QOT_SEC_ID, p2 = dpr.DPR_TS } 
    equals 
new { p1 = p.PAY_SEC_ID, p2 = p.PAY_DATE }
```

...which will find no matches if `PAY_SEC_ID` is `null`, or

```
new { p1 = q.QOT_SEC_ID, p2 = dpr.DPR_TS } 
    equals 
new { p1 = p.PAY_SEC_ID.GetValueOrDefault(), p2 = p.PAY_DATE }
```

...which defaults `p1` to `0` when `PAY_SEC_ID` is `null` and again no match will be found (assuming that ID values will never be `0`).

Comment: if we have one key as nullable & other is non nullable, then can't we join them by having some conversion?

Comment: Apparently you also have to put even just a single parameter into an object with named properties like this if you have a `where` after your `join`.

Comment: In my case, I had the same type but one of the variables was nullable: new { A = t.Hrco, B = t.Premp??0 }  I handled the null case.

Answer (score 16):

Hopefully this helps someone with a similar facepalm moment I just had, make sure the  object's property names are the same. The error displays itself as:

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inreference failed in the call to 'Join'

This is slightly misleading as this is the same message that appears when you have two value types that are different i.e. `int` and `double`.

What this actually meant in my case was that the two objects themselves were different types, not the values:

```
join count in productCount on new { tool.ItemNo, tool.ItemType } equals new { count.OrigNumber, count.ItemType }
```

This was generating the following objects; which are obviously not comparable.

`'a is new { int ItemNo, int ItemType }`

`'a is new { int OrigNumber, int ItemType }`

To correct this simply just name the OrigNumber field to ItemNo:

```
join count in productCount on new { tool.ItemNo, tool.ItemType } equals new { ItemNo = count.OrigNumber, count.ItemType }
```

Comment: Just adding to your point @SimonCurtis, my  join condition was     
on new { od.Order_No, od.Line_No } equals new {  id.order_No., id.Line_No }     and I was also getting the same error.
Here  the column names are case sensitive. Note the o is in small case in id.order_No.  Corrected the 'o' to 'O'

Comment: this definitely fixed the issue I was having so thank you very much!

Comment: Can you see what I am missing here?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68304878/the-type-of-one-of-the-expressions-in-the-join-clause-is-incorrect-type-inferen
 I am facing a similar issue. In my case, the property type and name are matched. Still getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that one of the columns has a type that is implicitly convertable to the other. Likely, `int` and `int?`. That's why `equals` implicitly converts and `new { X = 1 }` is incompatible with `new { X = (int?)1 }`.

Cast one of the conflicting columns to `int` or `int?` depending on whether nulls are possible or not. E.g.

```
new { Customer_ID = (int?)pl.Customer_ID, ... }
```

Admittedly, the compiler error in this particular case is quite unclear and does not point to the root cause.

(This answer was rescued from a deleted duplicate. Since it's more complete than the currently accepted one I'll add it.)

Answer (score 2):

In the original LINQ query, the where clause contains assignment, not comparison (i.e. need "==" instead of "=").