# Linq multiple join conditions using extra variables

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM transaction t
JOIN transactionDetail toTrans ON t.id = toTrans.tId and toTrans.FlowDirection= 1
JOIN transactionDetail fromTrans ON t.id = fromTrans.tId and fromTrans.FlowDirection= 0
```

Which I tried to recreate using anonymous types, as explained [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e09b50af-5ab4-4cfb-9617-ef2be339c17f/join-on-multiple-conditions?forum=linqprojectgeneral).

```
byte toFlow = 1;
byte fromFlow = 1;

from trans in data.Transactions
join toTrans in data.TransactionDetails on new {trans.id, toFlow} equals new {toTrans.tId, toTrans.FlowDirection}
join fromTrans in data.TransactionDetails on new { trans.id, fromFlow } equals new { fromTrans.tId, fromTrans.FlowDirection }
```

Flowdirection is always either 1 or 0, so I'm using the toFlow byte. This however, gives the error:

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184019/the-type-of-one-of-the-expressions-in-the-join-clause-is-incorrect-in-entity-fra) answer, both name and types need to match. Which would mean:

```
byte FlowDirection= 1;

from trans in data.Transactions
join toTrans in data.TransactionDetails on new {trans.id, FlowDirection} equals new {toTrans.tId, toTrans.FlowDirection}
join fromTrans in data.TransactionDetails on new { trans.id, FlowDirection} equals new { fromTrans.tId, fromTrans.FlowDirection }
```

Which works! However, the second join needs to have a FlowDirection of value 0 instead of 1. How can I change the value of FlowDirection? I can't change the name of the variable or subtract 1 inside the anonymous object, or else this would have been easy.

Comment: Why can't you just use two constants, or just cast literals `(byte)0` and `(byte)1` ?

Comment: Thanks Stuart, that worked for me! I now have {trans.id, FlowDirection = (byte)1}. I figured out the problem. When I subtracted 1 from the byte, it became an int as well. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941584/byte-byte-int-why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to expand on the commentary:

> Surely you can just use two constants (or literals)?, i.e.

```
from trans in data.Transactions
join toTrans in data.TransactionDetails 
  on new {ID = trans.id, Flow = (byte)1} 
  equals new {Id = toTrans.tId, Flow = toTrans.FlowDirection}
join fromTrans in data.TransactionDetails 
  on new { Id = trans.id, Flow = (byte)0} 
  equals new { Id = fromTrans.tId, Flow = fromTrans.FlowDirection }
```

> Could FlowDirect - 1 not work because it turns FlowDirect into an int instead? Does subtracting an int from a byte turn the byte into an int maybe? Otherwise, I really don't know why your code works.

Yes, you would need to cast the result back to byte (or the literal `1` to `byte` so that byte operator "-" is used)

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change the value of FlowDirection? I can't change the name of the variable or subtract 1 inside the anonymous object

To change your variable inside the anonymous object simply do:

```
new { fromTrans.tId, FlowDirection = fromTrans.FlowDirection - 1 }
```

for example.

Comment: Sadly not, this was what I tried as well in several forms. I get the same type error. FlowDirection -= 1 and FlowDirect = toTrans.FlowDirection - 1 don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea:

```
from trans in data.Transactions
join toTrans in data.TransactionDetails on trans.id equals new toTrans.tId
join fromTrans in data.TransactionDetails on trans.id equals fromTrans.tId
where toTrans.FlowDirection == 1 && fromTrans.FlowDirection == 1
```

I think this option should be easier to read.