# LINQ join query with ICollection

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
 public partial class Person : ModificationEntity
{
    public Person()
    {
        this.PersonCompanies = new List<PersonCompany>();
    }

    public System.Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PersonCompany> PersonCompanies { get; set; }
}

public partial class PersonCompany : ModificationEntity
{
    public System.Guid PersonCompanyId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

I need to query all the users given a list of companyids (List lstCompanyIds).

So I take all the PersonCompanyId's with the following query:

```
var qpc = (from c in lstCompanyIds
           join u in personCompanyService.GetPersonCompanies()
           on c equals u.CompanyId
           select u.PersonCompanyId).AsQueryable();
```

With this query, I want to get the users:

```
var query = from q in GetUsers()
             join q2 in qpc
             on q.PersonCompanies.Select(y => y.PersonCompanyId) equals q2
             select q;
```

But this gives a compile error "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'."
Obviously because I try to do a select to the collection of personcompanies. But how do I do this correctly? (Contains is not working either because I have two collections to compare...)

Comment: Have you checked this question and solution? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184019/the-type-of-one-of-the-expressions-in-the-join-clause-is-incorrect-in-entity-fra

Comment: Are `PersonCompanyId` and `q2` of the same type (*System.Guid*)?

Comment: @BurakKarakuş Yes, but can't figure out how this can solve my problem.

Comment: @Loetn Yes, they are. Hovering Q2 says: (range variable) Guid, overing y.PersonCompany says Guid.

Comment: i guess the problem is `on q.PersonCompanies.Select(y => y.PersonCompanyId) equals q2` means `on IEnumerable<Guid> equals IQueryable<Guid>`... that seems not correct as a join expression to me anyway...

Comment: @stefankmitph OK, but how to solve? I've set .AsQueryable() in the second query, but nog luck. Removing the .AsQueryable() from setting qpc variable gives the same error.

Comment: @JurgenStillaert i'm no expert, but joining on two (generic) collections (as keys) as clause is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

```
    var qpc = (from res in
                      (from c in lstCompanyIds
                       join u in personCompanyService.GetPersonCompanies()
                       on c equals u.CompanyId
                       select u.PersonCompanyId)
                   join u in GetUser()
                  on res equals u.UserId
                  select u).AsQueryable();
```

I think this should work

Make sure all ID you are comparing are of type `System.Guid`

Comment: I've made some modifications and it seems to work (u.PersonCompanyId => u.PersonId and res equals u.PersonId). I have to test some more, but seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are making comparison of `IQueryable<Guid>` with `Guid`. If I understood you correctly, that is what you are trying to achieve:

```
IQueryable<Guid> companyIds = Enumerable.Empty<Guid>().AsQueryable(); //qpc in your question
IQueryable<Person> persons = Enumerable.Empty<Person>().AsQueryable(); //q in your question
var result = persons.Where(person => person.PersonCompanies
            .Any(company => companyIds.Contains(company.CompanyId)));
```

Comment: I tried this, but not getting any result retuned (and it should). I'm trying to get this figured out.

Comment: @JurgenStillaert both input collections are non-empty, you get no exceptions and errors, but the result is empty?