# System.Linq Linq queries not working in VS2012 but works fine in VS2010

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have a linq query that works fine in VS2010 and VS2012 on system where code was originally, written but when commited to SVN, and pulled to new system, Code does not built. The same code works fine in 2 systems but fails in other 3 system each of them having VS2012, .NET Framework 4.0 (Target Framework).

Not sure what's wrong with the code. I understand the code written is having bugs and is written terribly wrong way.

Here is sample linq query that works fine in VS2010 but fails in VS2012.

```
from d in db.VacancyCandidates
join c in db.Candidates on new 
    { CandidateId = d.CandidateId, CandidateType = d.CandidateType}
equals new { CandidateId = c.CandidateId, CandidateType = c.CanidateTypeId }          
........Rest query ......
```

From above query `d.CandidateType` is `Nullable<int>` and `c.CanidateTypeId` is int.

I looked at following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184019/the-type-of-one-of-the-expressions-in-the-join-clause-is-incorrect-in-entity-fra/19184145?noredirect=1#comment67824125_19184145) and if I change the `d.CandidateType` to `d.CandidateType.Value` then code builds correctly.

**My question is why the code builds in VS2010 and not in VS2012 no my machine?**

Adding further screenshots which may help you.
[image: Errors]
[image: References]

**More information related compilers:**

[image]

Pls. know that on all system, the target framework for the project is 4.0 only. Above information is retrived using `CSC /?` command `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\V4.0.3.319\`

Comment: What error/exception do you get?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it works in VS2010 (could be a compiler bug) because the code is wrong. Add `= (int?)c.CandidateTypeId` and move on.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm already moving on by changing the code, But I'm trying to understand what made wrong code working fine in VS2010 & VS2012 on original system but fails on others. It's a curious question to me!

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to the why it works in VS2010 in a, most likely, older version of the C# compiler.

Nowadays the compiler will use the `Type` and `Name` of the referenced members to determine which anonymous type it needs to generate.

It will try to match up any anonymous types which have exactly the same signature. So `new { A = "1" }` and `new { A = "2" }` will have the same type, but `new { A = "1" }` and `new { A = 1 }` will not.

The first anonymous type it will generate likely has a `CandidateId` and `CandidateType`  with types `int` and `int?` respectively. 
For the second anonymous type, it will verify if any other types have that exact same signature. Which isn't the case here, as `CandidateType` is of type `int` in the second initializer.

As said, in order to have the signatures match, you need to ensure the types align.

```
from d in db.VacancyCandidates
join c in db.Candidates on new { CandidateId = d.CandidateId, CandidateType = d.CandidateType}
equals new { CandidateId = c.CandidateId, CandidateType = (int?)c.CanidateTypeId }
```

Beware that consuming the value of a `Nullable<>` type will fail when the value is `null`. So your proposed solution of going `d.CandidateType.Value` *might* be dangerous.
It "*Might*" be dangerous because dependent on whether you are directly querying a database via Linq-to-SQL or EntityFramework, or working in memory the behavior is different.

Consuming the `.Value` of a `null` `Nullable<>` will thrown a `InvalidOperationException` when executed as an in memory lambda, but will not in case it is translated to a SQL query, as the `QueryProvider` is smart enough to fix this.

Comment: Exactly and that's why I wrote... The code is written terribly wrong. The code that I'm looking into is written by someone and is being large scale application. I'm uncertain of changing those Nullable to non-nullable type since I'm looking at code at very high level having not insight of what's going on underneath. My job for this specific error is to make the code working in all systems without chaning any code. I know it sounds crazy but that's what I'm dealing with.

Comment: I also doubt, why same code is compling on other systems having VS2012 and fails on my system having same version of VS2012. I know this has to do with environment differences and that's what I'm figuring out.

Comment: @HirenDesai Compare the compiler versions between both environments. This is likely the cause of the difference in behavior.

Comment: Both systems are having same VS 2012 version and C# compiler version 4.0.30319.34209

Comment: Hmm, that shouldn't be. Verify that both compilers have the `dynamic` keyword. This was added in the 4.0 release of the compiler.

Comment: Added a statement in code for a dynamic variable in that works in both the system.