# System.LINQ double inner join?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to get all of X from XY table.  X being a table and Y being a table, and XY being a XREF table.

The code below is my attempt. However I for some reason cannot double join?   Any System.LINQ pros out there able to help me understand how XREF tables work in System.LINQ?

```
public async Task<List<FunctionModel>> GetFunctionsByTestCaseID(string pID, CancellationToken pCancellationToken)
{
    pCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    return await (from F in Context.Functions
        join TS in Context.TestSteps on F.ID equals TS.FunctionID
        join X in Context.XREF_TestCases_TestSteps on TS.ID equals X.TestStepID
        where X.TestCaseID == pID
        select F).ToListAsync();         
}
```

ERROR:

> CS1941    The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is
>   incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

UPDATE:

Here is the equivalent SQL statement, maybe that will clear things up.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Functions F
INNER JOIN dbo.TestSteps TS ON TS.FunctionID = F.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.XREF_TestCases_TestSteps X ON X.TestStepID = TS.ID
WHERE X.TestCaseID = 1
```

Comment: Any chance you can post details of your model/schema? It looks like a type error in the type of one or more properties.

Comment: from just the two tables?

Comment: surely , the join's aparently are correct, have to be model mistake i think so.

Comment: If `XREF` is a many-to-many mapping/bridge table then it should be joined between the other two tables, but then I don't get why `TestSteps` as a `FunctionID` which indicates a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: So, each test step has single function with potentially multiple parameters.  Test Step is a 1 to many to function. Function is a 1 to many to parameter table.  

I want all the functions for a single test case. and a test case is a many to many to test steps.

Comment: Update to be more clear

Comment: My bet is that ID on one and the ID on the other are different types. 
 Possible duplicate of [The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184019/the-type-of-one-of-the-expressions-in-the-join-clause-is-incorrect-in-entity-fra)