# The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.- Linq JOIN with multiple condition

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

This might get closed for a possible duplicate of this: [The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect in Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184019/the-type-of-one-of-the-expressions-in-the-join-clause-is-incorrect-in-entity-fra/19184145)
*But I would request to not close this without reading this whole problem.*

Although it might seem to be a duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184019/the-type-of-one-of-the-expressions-in-the-join-clause-is-incorrect-in-entity-fra/19184145), I would request to give this a read and help if possible. I have seen the solutions to the same question I linked, it is described that the property type and the name must match. I carefully read the solutions over there and made sure mine was following each of them.

However, I could not find any property type and name mismatch error in my code. So I am guessing there is something else that I am missing. Hence looking for help creating a separate question.

So I am trying to write `LINQ Join` with `Multiple Conditions` in `On` Clause. I have written them making sure the object's properties are of same type and name. Nevertheless I am getting the infamous misleading error - ***The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'***.

Following is my code:

```
              results = from i in context.Invoices.AsNoTracking()
                        join iwr in context.InvoiceWorkOrderRelations on i.ID equals iwr.InvoiceId
                        join w in context.WorkOrders on iwr.WorkOrderId equals w.ID
                        join scr in context.StationCompanyRelations 
                            on new { Company = w.CompanyID ?? -1, Station = w.RepairLocation ?? -1 } equals new { Comapny = (int)?scr.CompanyID, Station= (int)?scr.StationID }
    
                        where i.IsDeleted == false
                    && (companyID == Company.SYSTEMCOMPANYID || i.CompanyId == companyID)
                        orderby i.ID descending
                        select new DTO.InvoiceQuickView
                        {
                            ID = i.ID,
                            ....
                            ShopCode = scr.ShopCode
                        };
```

`CompanyID` and `RepairLocation` from `WorkOrders` context both are of type int?, hence, I type casted the relation table and stringly provided names for each property just to make sure.

Also to handle null values, I added `w.CompanyID ?? -1`. The error remains with or without this null checking.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a lot of trying and searching I found the solution. Thanks to @Meysam Asadi who brought a point about typecasting the anonymous types inside linq, but to add to that statement type names must also match. I found out the issue with his solution was the second property of both object (RepairLocation and StationID) are not same and that's why compiler was still throwing the same error.

I don't know why the other solutions were sugesting typecasting though. In my case it is the typecasting that was mainly causing this error.

```
                    join w in context.WorkOrders on iwr.WorkOrderId equals w.ID
                    join scr in context.StationCompanyRelations on 
                       new { Company = w.CompanyID ?? -1, Station = w.RepairLocation ?? -1 } equals 
                       new { Comapny = scr.CompanyID, Station= scr.StationID }
```

So, *while writing linq to join tables with multiple condition on `ON` clause*:-

You **must match the property names** and you **must handle for nullable values if one propertiy from one table is `nullable` whilst the other one is `not null`**.

Comment: So the answer is in fact just the answer for the question you said wasn't a duplicate.

Comment: The solutions were suggesting typecasting and that is where I was getting it wrong. In my case the type casting (int)? was throwing the error.

Comment: I am ready to remove this or close this if it violates the community standard. I needed help and the existing solutions did not seem to solve my issue. and thanks to @Meysam Asadi, who wrote an answer which made me understand what was the issue actually. Thanks for your feed back anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use conversion or direct conversion functions inside the `linq` expression, which must be `anonymous`.

To `join` two tables with two parameters, both fields must have the same type I below your code:

```
 results = from i in context.Invoices.AsNoTracking()
                      join iwr in context.InvoiceWorkOrderRelations on i.ID equals iwr.InvoiceId
                      join w in context.WorkOrders on iwr.WorkOrderId equals w.ID
                      join scr in context.StationCompanyRelations
                          on new { w.CompanyID, w.RepairLocation } equals new { scr.CompanyID, scr.StationID }

                      where i.IsDeleted == false
                  && (companyID == Company.SYSTEMCOMPANYID || i.CompanyId == companyID)
                      orderby i.ID descending
                      select new DTO.InvoiceQuickView
                      {
                          ID = i.ID,
                          ....ShopCode = scr.ShopCode
                      };
```

in line code

```
join scr in context.StationCompanyRelations
                          on new { w.CompanyID, w.RepairLocation } equals new { scr.CompanyID, scr.StationID }
```

The compiler automatically compares the first field of the first anonymous linq expression with the same field in the second expression, and also compares the second field of the first anonymous link expression with the second anonymous linq expression with the second field.

Use [DefaultIfEmpty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=net-5.0) if you want the values to match if they are empty.
The following code shows how to do it.

```
 results = from i in context.Invoices.AsNoTracking()
                      join iwr in context.InvoiceWorkOrderRelations on i.ID equals iwr.InvoiceId
                      join w in context.WorkOrders on iwr.WorkOrderId equals w.ID
                      join scr in context.StationCompanyRelations
                          on new { w.CompanyID, w.RepairLocation } equals new { scr.CompanyID, scr.StationID }
                          into lj
                      where i.IsDeleted == false
                  && (companyID == Company.SYSTEMCOMPANYID || i.CompanyId == companyID)
                      orderby i.ID descending
                     from x in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new DTO.InvoiceQuickView
                      {
                          ID = i.ID,
                          ....ShopCode = scr.ShopCode
                      };
```

Comment: So, you are suggesting I can not join properties that are nullable in one table and not null in another table?

Comment: The solution you gave was my first attempt. I was getting this error while I tried your approach. After that, I searched and it seems like people are getting it done by type casting. Please see this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/19184145/3939811

Comment: I had looked at it before and tested it, but the compiler gives an error. I edited the answer. You can use DefaultIfEmpty() for empty values.

Comment: In my case the compiler still throwing errors with DefaultEmpty()

Comment: The same one was described in the question.

Comment: That error for on new {Company = w.CompanyID ?? -1, Station = w.RepairLocation ?? -1} equals new {Comapny = (int)? Scr.CompanyID, Station = (int)? Scr.StationID}

Comment: Please use the codes I provided in the answer.

Comment: @TasnimFabiha If you use the code I put, you should not get a compiler error.

Comment: I was trying with your code and still getting the error, then I found out the issue is that the property name must also match.  The compiler does not automatically compare anonymous properties with different names.

Comment: The compiler does not compare anonymous properties name but compares their values !!

Comment: For example the value on new {c.Id} equals new {d.OrderId}

Comment: This seems to be the case, I don't know why. But yes names were the issue in my case :(